# error: conflicting types for ‘atoll’

Tags: c, debugging, import, server

I'm trying to debug so I can host a game server this is the next error in my way. I've only been on Linux for a short period of time and have no idea where to go from here.

This is the error I'm working with:

```
server $ make
gcc -Wall -Wshadow -Wno-pointer-sign -O3 -g -fno-strict-aliasing -m32     -DSTAFF -o .obj/server.o -c server.c
In file included from server.c:57:0:
tool.h:24:20: error: conflicting types for ‘atoll’
 unsigned long long atoll(char *string);
                    ^
In file included from /usr/include/features.h:374:0,
                 from /usr/include/stdio.h:27,
                 from server.c:32:
/usr/include/stdlib.h:292:1: note: previous definition of ‘atoll’ was here
 __NTH (atoll (const char *__nptr))
 ^
make: *** [.obj/server.o] Error 1
```

Comment: are you trying to build Astonia?

Comment: If this is Astonia, you should [contact the author](http://brockhaus.org/).

Answer (score 3):

`atoll` is a standard C library function, declared in `<stdlib.h>`, introduced in C99.

Its declaration is:

```
long long int atoll(const char *nptr);
```

Apparently the software you're compiling has a header file called `tool.h` that declares:

```
unsigned long long atoll(char *string);
```

That declaration is incorrect and unnecessary.  It might make sense to declare `atoll` explicitly *if* the underlying implementation doesn't support it, but it should at least be declared correctly -- and it shouldn't be declared at all if `<stdlib.h>` already declares it.

The software you're building is either buggy or misconfigured.  If you can identify the software (is it an open source package?), we can take a look at it. Or you might contact the author and point out this problem.

Based on some of the comments, it's likely you're trying to build Astonia. I've downloaded the source myself, and it has the problem you report (though with a different line number; perhaps you're not building the latest version). The source declares, but does not define, the `atoll` function. Commenting out the declaration should address this specific problem, though there could be others. You should [contact the author](http://brockhaus.org/).

Answer (score 1):

[`atoll()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/atoll/) is a C++ standard library (stdlib) conversion function.

It looks like you're hitting two different definitions of it in two different header files.  Why is your `server.c` using `#include#` to pull in two conflicting chains of header `.h` files?

Many C and C++ open source packages have a `./configure` command. Should you re-run that command if you have one?

Comment: I'm pretty new to this stuff, so I'm unsure. Along with that there no dependency or list of debugs that came with the source. What do you think I should do, remove one of the files or independantly declare them. Not sure I could do the latter on my own, but, I'm not afraid to break my installation, either. I can get back to this error with ease

Comment: `atoll` is a *C* standard library function. (It's also available in C++, but the OP asked about C.)

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume I know what you're trying to build, because I just went through this myself and saw the exact same error. The problem is, this code was built a decade or so ago on 32-bit linux, and this conflict did not exist. Now you're (another assumption by me) trying to build it on 64-bit linux and there's a conflict. I don't have the C wherewithal to fix the issue by altering code, however, if you try to build this on a 32-bit version of linux, it will work.

Let me *also* say that if you go down the path of fixing this issue on a 64-bit system, it will not be the last of your troubles. You're going to hit another wall when the 32-bit MySQL pieces are hit in the build process and do not exist on your 64-bit system.

Comment: Even a decade ago, C99 had `atoll()` — but maybe the C library in use at the time did not.  But this is an example of how software (source code) can 'rot' with the passage of time, even though it does not change — in fact, because it does not change.  The surrounding infrastructure changes, and what was valid a decade ago ceases to be valid now.

Comment: In principle, the fix is to remove (comment out) the line 24 in the file `tool.h` which contains: `unsigned long long atoll(char *string);`.  However, if the code assumes that `atoll()` returns an unsigned (rather than signed) `long long`, there could be more trouble to be resolved than that.  Another option would be to rename the function to `atoull()` — which is not provided in standard C — and to find all the places where the old name is invoked and replace it with the new one; a simple global search-and-replace on the exact word should do the job.

Comment: Resist the temptation to just cut out the project's custom `atoll` function .. it may behave differently to ISO C's `atoll` and the project may rely on the differences, and it'd be hard to debug if there was a problem introduced

Comment: @M.M: If the OP is compiling [Astonia](http://www.astonia.com/), I've downloaded the source. It *declares* `atoll` in `tool.h` (though not on the same line reported by the OP; it's probably a different version), but it never defines it.  And the declaration is surrounded by `#if __GNUC_MINOR__==8`, which doesn't make a whole lot of sense.